# Unable to retrieve original URL in QNetworkReply after finished() signal

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have a basic Qt application which generates a number of QNetworkRequests in a loop, using a QNetworkAccessManager to get() them before generating more requests. This works fine and I get the expected responses from the server in the QNAM's finished() slot.

In the slot processing the QNetworkReply instance I have to obtain a number of items from the original request, which I obtain via the request() function in the QNetworkReply instance provided to this function. I can successfully obtain the HTTP status and the raw headers as I set them in the original request.

I can however not retrieve the original URL, as the url() function of the request returns nothing. I also tried to set the URL as a property on the QNetworkReply pointer obtained from the QNAM and read it out in the finished() slot, but this also failed for some reason.

The relevant bits of code in the main loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hprCount; i++) {
        QNetworkRequest request;
        QMapIterator<QString, QString> it(headerParamResult[i]);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            it.next();            
            request.setRawHeader(it.key().toLatin1(), it.value().toLatin1());
        }

        QString urlString = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < qprCount; j++) {
            QUrl url("http://localhost:8888/page");
            QMapIterator<QString, QString> jt(queryParamResult[j]);
            QUrlQuery query;
            while (jt.hasNext()) {
                jt.next();
                query.setProperty(jt.key(), jt.value());
            }

            request.setQuery(query);
            urlString = url.toString();
        }

        request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
        QNetworkReply* reply = testNam->get(request);
        reply->setProperty("url", QVariant(urlString));
        qApp->processEvents();
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(processHttpError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    }
```

And the finished slot:

```
if (reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt() == 200) { return; }

QNetworkRequest request = reply->request();
QList<QByteArray> headers = request.rawHeaderList();
QByteArray headersString;
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    headersString += headers[i];
}

/*QUrl reqUrl(reply->request().url());
QString url = reqUrl.toString();*/
QString url = reply->property("url").toString();
```

I originally used the single QNetworkRequest instance I obtain in the beginning, but that made no difference. The return value from either the property method or url() function is always an empty string.

In the debugger the QUrl instance (here commented out) is listed as '' in the debugger. What this means I am not sure.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hello, I try a minimal [example](https://gist.github.com/vannell/16b8d6f4dc7e21fa0431) and does not found problems. Maybe your request causes some errors (could you remove this `qApp->processEvents()` before connection your slots?), because of your url's parameters encoding. See the [Qt4.8 doc](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html#addQueryItem)

Comment: I had to add the qApp->processEvents() call because otherwise finished() would not be called (blocked eventloop for some reason...). I figured that QUrl can properly parse a query string like this? Thanks.

Comment: I am using a QUrlQuery instance now to create the query parameter string, but with the same result. The url() function returns an <invalid> according to the debugger and the url string is always empty.

Comment: I assume your request succeed as you test http status code. You can perhaps be sure by testing `QNetworkReply::error() == QNetworkReply::NoError`. I have to say I've few idea to help you now..Could you post the list of url's parameters you are encoding, and your new version of code with QUrlQuery?

Comment: I had to comment out the check for NoError as I'd keep getting QNetworkReply::UnknownContentError responses for some reason, even though the response data (saved HTML files to disk) looked just fine after removing that check. As for the exact parameters, I can not give these as I'm under NDA :) They're all fairly generic, though. I'll update my post with the new code.